# How to make 'click event' is a custom user control's?

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I have a problem to handle mouse click event on dynamic object. I have 2 form, a main form called FormMain and another customized form called FormView, I create a component base on PictureBox class like this:

```
public class customPB : PictureBox
{
        public customPB()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Width = 195;
            this.Height = 114;
            this.Visible = true;
            this.Invalidate();
        }
        .
        .
        private void BtnLink_Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Button Click Event");
        }
        .
        .
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.btnAmazon = new Button();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // btnLink
            // 
            this.btnLink.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.btnLink.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.LinkIcon;
            this.btnLink.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(9, 70);
            this.btnLink.Name = "btnLink";
            this.btnLink.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(34, 34);
            this.btnLink.TabIndex = 1;
            this.btnLink.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(BtnLink_Click);

            this.Controls.Add(this.btnLink);
            this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(195, 114);
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }
}
```

In my project , I created "FormView" form like this:

```
    class FormView : Form
    {
        public FormView(Form windowParent, Point windowPosition ,Size windowSize )
        {
            _windowPosition = windowPosition;
            this.Owner=windowParent;
            InitializeComponent();
            windowParent.LocationChanged += FormView_LocationChanged;
            this.Location = windowParent.PointToScreen(windowPosition);
            this.ClientSize = windowSize;
            this.Show(windowParent);
        }

        private void FormView_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                custPB = new customPB();
                this.Controls.Add(custPB);
            }
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.SuspendLayout();
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 261);
            this.Name = "OverlayWindow";
            this.DoubleBuffered = true;
            this.MaximizeBox = false;
            this.MinimizeBox = false;
            this.ShowIcon = false;
            this.ControlBox = false;
            this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            this.Paint += FormView_Paint;
            this.MouseDoubleClick += FormView_MouseDoubleClick;
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
        }
        protected override void OnActivated(EventArgs e)
        {
            // Always keep the owner activated instead
            this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => this.Owner.Activate()));
        }
   }
```

In main form , I create new "FormView" like this:

```
        private FormView frm1 ;
        public frmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            FormView frm1 = new FormView(this);
            FormView.Visible = true;
        }
```

When I click on btnLink in custom PictureBox component, nothing happens, what's my mistake?
Try to fire click event on button in custom components created dynamical.
thanks

try to fire click event on button in custom components created dynamical

Comment: i add a label to my customized picturebox component ,and try to test click event, that's work fine by this code : this.lblItemName.Click += LblItemName_Click;

Comment: customPB.InitializeComponent looks wrong. It creates a btnAmazon does not add  it to the control collection but then does setup on a btnLink.

Comment: yes you right, i edited my mistak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the event handler:

```
protected override void OnActivated(EventArgs e)
{
    // Always keep the owner activated instead
    this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => this.Owner.Activate()));
}
```

By calling this.Owner.Activate() you are giving focus to the parent form and customPB loses the focus, preventing the click event from working correctly.

Comment: @Mehdi let me know if it works for you

Comment: sure, thanks, i will do it

Comment: @Mehdi could you make it work?

Comment: Thanks Jarmanso , i comment this line and my code work correctly :)))